# How to check events are delegated or not in unit testing using mocking in c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-8, mocking

I declared events in X class.
I delegated those events in Y class constructor.
I am writing unit test cases for constructor in Y class using mocking.
Normally when we call constructor events will be delegated.
So i want test whether those events are delegated or not using unit test cases.
How can i do it?
Here is my code.

```
public class X
{
     public event EventHandler<MessageStatusChangedEventArgs> MessageStateChanged;

     public void someMethod()
     {
          if(MessageStateChanged!=null)
             new MessageStatusChangedEventArgs(someParams);
     }
}

public class Y
{
    public Y()
    {
       xObject.MessageStateChanged+=messageStateChanged;
    }
}
```

Unit test cases

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
   Mock<X> xMock=new Mock<X>();
   Mock<Y> yMock=new Mock<Y>();
   //Here How to test whether those events are delegated or not.  
}
```

Comment: You need to change code to:

`var handler = this.MessageStateChanged;
if ( handler != null)
   handler(this, new MessageStatusChangedEventArgs(someParams);`

Comment: How does the constructor of `class Y` get `xObject`? Is it passed in? Also, you don't mean to be mocking `class Y` in the unit test, right? That seems to be the class under test...

Comment: Yes..i am passing instance of x class.And also i mocked class y to unit test.